# Get html tags from string in PHP

Tags: php

How gets html tags from string?
For example, I have string: `$text="<a>Text1</a><b>ABCD</b> <a href="">Some</a> Text3"`;

How can I get tags to array `$arr : <a> , </a>, <b> , </b>, <a>, </a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('$</?\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(?:".*?"|\\'.*?\\'|[^'">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/?>$', $text, $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

The resulst is here `$arr`

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
But how get open tags and close tags in two different arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Use those expressions:

`<[^\/][^>]*>` for opening (and self closing like `<br />`) tags: https://regex101.com/r/558dsy/2

`<\/[^>]+>` for closing tags: https://regex101.com/r/VBzbwh/3